# How to preserve the task state when Unwrapping

Tags: asynchronous, .net-4.5

Please, observe the following trivial .NET 4.5 code:

```
var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<object>("Hello");
var t1 = tcs.Task;
var t2 = t1.ContinueWith((t, state) => 0, "Hello");
var t3 = t2.ContinueWith((t, state) => new Task<int>(_ => 0, state), "Hello");
var t4 = t3.Unwrap();

Trace.Assert("Hello".Equals(t1.AsyncState), "t1.AsyncState is broken!");
Trace.Assert("Hello".Equals(t2.AsyncState), "t2.AsyncState is broken!");
Trace.Assert("Hello".Equals(t3.AsyncState), "t3.AsyncState is broken!");
Trace.Assert("Hello".Equals(t4.AsyncState), "t4.AsyncState is broken!");
```

The last assertion fails, which breaks my code (slightly less contrived than this sample).

My question is how to make the task state survive unwrapping? Is there a way to manually unwrap with the state preservation?

Answer (score 2):

Right now, I do not see any other option, except avoiding the default `Unwrap()` method. Instead, I found the following workaround to be adequate:

```
var t4 = t3.ContinueWith((t, _) => t.Result.Result, t3.AsyncState);
```

I will package it as my own extension method, something like `FixedUnwrap()`:

```
public static Task<TResult> FixedUnwrap<TResult>(this Task<Task<TResult>> task)
{
  return task.ContinueWith((t, _) => t.Result.Result, task.AsyncState);
}
```

**IMPORTANT UPDATE**

The proposed implementation is wrong! The unwrapped task must continue when the nested task is done, whereas the given version continues when the wrapper task is done. It is very wrong.

Please, find below the correct one (two versions):

```
    public static Task TaskUnwrap(this Task<Task> task)
    {
        return task.Unwrap().ContinueWith((t, _) =>
        {
            if (t.Exception != null)
            {
                throw t.Exception;
            }
        }, task.AsyncState);
    }

    public static Task<TResult> TaskUnwrap<TResult>(this Task<Task<TResult>> task)
    {
        return task.Unwrap().ContinueWith((t, _) => t.Result, task.AsyncState);
    }
```

Comment: I don't think your custom Unwrap has the same error propagation semantics. Apart from that, it seems to be a good solution.

Comment: I'd be happy to improve it. Any suggestions?